# How to use Instance Method with Lamda, Threads and Named Arugments

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, lambda

The current code below produces an error. I keep tweaking the syntax but keep getting errors. I know I am close. I am tring to use a lambda inside an instance method, to start a thread and the target is an instance method with named arguments. I am seeing various forms of wrong positional arguments  Can anyone help?

```
      arguments = {'resource_group_name': resource_group_name,
                'vm_name': vm_name,
                'script': script,
                'parameters': parameters,
                'command_id': command_id}

        thread = Thread(name=vm_name,
                            target=lambda self, q, **kwargs: q.put(self.run_command(kwargs)),
                            args=(que, arguments))
        thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it working with this:

```
        thread = Thread(name=vm_name,
                            target=lambda self, q, kwargs: q.put(self.run_command(**kwargs)),
                            args=(self, que, arguments))
```